# Using seperated test and train files with train_test_split()

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, training-data, train-test-split

I have two `.csv` files that one of them is `test.csv` and the other one is `train.csv`. However, as you can predict the test file does not have the `target column` ('y' in this case) while train file has.

What I wanted to do is first using train file to train the system entirely, then using the test file just to see predictions.

I'm using `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split()` to create train and test examples but it accepts 1 file path only. I want to train the system using train file first, then when it finished I want to get test datas from `test.csv` file and make the predictions.

So first I tried classic way but decreasing test size so It'll be like "this file used for train only",

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import SVC
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'path\train.csv', sep=",")
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
       X, y, test_size = 0.001, random_state = 45)

clf = SVC(kernel = 'rbf')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

but then, when it comes to real test part(which I want to use the data in test.csv that doesn't have target values), how can I import test.csv somehow I can use the test data in trained model above

```
#get data from test.csv as somehow X_test
clfPredict = clf.predict(X_test)
```

If this is not possible using `train_test_split()`, what's the proper way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the train CSV and split it to:

```
y_train = df1['Y column']
X_train = df1.drop('Y Column', axis = 1)
```

And regarding test:

```
X_test = df2
```

and y_test will be the result from clf.predict(X_test)